# How to fix "No Log4j 2 configuration file found" in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j, log4j2, netbeans-8

I am trying to configure Log4j2 in Netbeans.

I have used following code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
        logger.trace("Configuration File Defined To Be :: "+System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile"));
    }
}
```

When i right click and run i am getting following error message:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

currently, My project structure looks like below: (Netbeans project)

[image]

As suggested by related questioners, I am trying to make src/main/resources and put configuration file under same and also tried to put it under src(source packages) but unable to fix that error. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing name of configuration file to `log4j2.xml`

By default, `log4j2` searches for file with name `log4j2` on application classpath (under src/main/resources/ directory)